# Path routing for file extension in EKS AWS ALB Ingress Controller (AWS Load Balancer Controller controller)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have created an EKS using AWS ALB Ingress Controller and also created a ingress for the same. But after creating the ingress, I am getting **404** while accessing some file extension. Ex: main.css.  Following is my ingress code.

```
--- 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  annotations: 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: my-site
  namespace: my-site
spec: 
  rules: 
    - 
      host: my-site.com
      http: 
        paths: 
          - 
            backend: 
              service: 
                name: my-site-front-end-service
                port: 
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Exact
          - 
            backend: 
              service: 
                name: my-site-backend-service
                port: 
                  number: 3000
            path: /marketing/
            pathType: Prefix
```

My frontend application needs to be available on `HTTP://my-site.com` and the backend service in the URL `HTTP://my-site.com/marketing/`.But now I am getting 404 for some of the .css files. The URL for the files are like, HTTP://my-site.com/main.css , HTTP://my-site.com//main-5a17625f9c68d9c60c4c.js .  What is wrong with my ingress configuration?

When I update the path type to prefix in the frotend-service section, all the calls will be forwarded to frontend hence the calls to the backend service don't work.

Comment: http://my-site.com  = frontend 

http://my-site.com/marketing/v1  = Backend 


Backend url is  http://my-site.com/marketing/v1 , so I cannot add path / with pathtype as prefix since this will make to forward all requests to frontend. So even backed service call also forwarding to front-end

Answer (score 1):

Your ingress endpoint `/` is of type `ExactMatch`. Therefore, the files matching `/*` will *not be matched*. You can change this to type `Prefix` and it should work.

Additionally, consider moving your files away from the root of the path to somewhere like `/files/` and then use `/files` as a `prefix` type ingress route. This will make sure the `/` path remains `exactmatch` so as not to confuse it with other paths.

Comment: Thank's for your comment. When I add path / with prefix as PathType then calls for the backend service will not work. All the calls will forward to front-end service only.
+++++++++++
http://my-site.com  = frontend => will work

,http://my-site.com/marketing/v1  = Backend => will not work

+++++++++++

Comment: Ingress paths are always matched by `longest match` principle. Which means if you specify `/` and `/marketing/` as two `Prefix` type paths, even though `/marketing/something` matches both, it will be served by the `/marketing/` rule, since it has a longer match. Please check if your service endpoint is correct, the one you're testing with. And the service is running.